# Regex to Match Quoted Strings Ignoring Double Quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match quoted strings in an Excel style formula:

```
= "Red" & "Blue" & "Green"
```

The following regex finds the matches nicely:

```
".*?"
```

Where I'm having problems though is where the match contains Excel/VBScript escaped quotes (two quotes together):

```
= "Red" & "Blue" & """Green"" as grass"
```

I want the double quotes captured inside the one match so I end up with: `"Red"`, `"Blue"`, `"""Green"" as grass"`.

I'm doing this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this regex will suit you:

```
/"(?:[^"]|"")*"/g
```

Explanation:

1. A susbtring that starts with a double quote
2. With anything not quote or double double quote inside
3. Followed by a quote char

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S22Qe/

Regex101: http://regex101.com/r/mJ0pX0/1